# How to Pass an Array to a Fortran DLL using DLLImport without mangling it in the process?

Tags: c#, arrays, fortran, pinvoke, dllimport

I am trying to pass an array into a Fortran DLL using the following DLLImport statement

```
[DllImport("MyFortranDLL.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
static extern void sDTransposeSTDCALL(ref int n1, ref int n2, [In]double[,] doubles, [Out]double[,] aTransposed);
```

My C# code that calls it looks like this

```
public double[,] TransposeStd(double[,] a)
{
    int n1 = a.GetLength(0);
    int n2 = a.GetLength(1);
    double[,] aTransposed = new double[n2, n1];

    sDTransposeSTDCALL(ref n1, ref n2, a, aTransposed);
    return aTransposed;
}
```

When I pass the following array

```
var a = new double[,] { { 11, 12 }, { 21, 22 }, { 31, 32 } };
```

I have the fortran DLL print out a text file with what it interprets the array as and it prints out this

```
     A( 1, 1 ) =   11.000
     A( 1, 2 ) =   22.000
     A( 2, 1 ) =   12.000
     A( 2, 2 ) =   31.000
     A( 3, 1 ) =   21.000
     A( 3, 2 ) =   32.000
```

However, these numbers are in switched positions.  For example `A(1,2)` should equal 12 and not 22.

What is going on here and how do I fix it?

Comment: Numbers are in switched positions... i.e. A(1,2) should equal 12 and not 22.

Comment: `A(1,2)` is the fourth element of the array `A` of shape `[3,2]`.

Comment: We can't see your Fortran code

Comment: @DavidHeffernan my fortran code just prints out the array, nothing weird

Comment: @francescalus I believe that is the problem, in a C(#) world, it is my understanding that, A(1,2) is the second item, not the 4th.

Comment: Check out the terms *row-major* and *column-major* as they apply to the storage order of 2(and higher)-D arrays.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I have run across these terms, but haven't really figured out a way to cleanly handle the different implementations with DLLImport

Comment: Asking us to help with code that you conceal is not cool. But yes, row/col major is the issue

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My intention was to not busy up the question with unnecessary code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-dimensional arrays are stored row major in .net and col major in Fortran. That explains the behaviour.

In order to resolve the mismatch you need to transpose the data. You can choose to do this at either side, on the .net side or the Fortran side. But you cannot get either language to do it for you.

On the C# side, for instance of the array has dimensions m by n allocate an array of dimensions n by m. Copy element i, j from original array to element j, i of the copy. Then pass the copy to the Fortran code.